# SSMS Query to Text File

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a complicated query that marshals data to a temporary table, which I then marshal into a further output temporary table before finally selecting on it to display to screen. This gets saved out from Grid view, to text and I get the file I need for processing off site.

What I want to do is have this query be run-able and create that file on the local disk without any need for the operator to change the "Results to" option, or fiddle with anything.

What command or functionality might be available to me to do this?

I can not install any stored procedures or similar to the server involved.

Comment: When you say you can't install any stored procedures to the server do you just mean the existing databases?  Would it be possible to create a new database to hold your code?  This is a fairly common practice on instances that are used for vendor databases.

Comment: Nothing can be installed to the server period, so no you can't parcel it into an SP and recommend BCP :o)

Comment: Can you create a scheduled task? You could use osql with redirection to a file. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic424456-8-1.aspx#bm424460

Comment: No, I can not add a scheduled task.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't do anything on the server I would suggest writing an SSIS package.  Create a data flow, and in your source object put your script.  Your destination object will then point to the file you want.  You have a fair number of options for output.

The SSIS package can then be run by

1. A SQL Job (assuming you are allowed even that)
2. A non SQL job running a bat file with a DTEXEC command
3. The DTEXECUI GUI.

Also you can store your SSIS package in the instance or on any fileshare you choose.

Comment: This sounds reasonable but I've never opened BIDS or an SSIS package before. Seem to have got 95% there by having a stab but sadly can't set up a succesful source. My query is probably too complicated to just paste in as a SQL Command it seems.

Comment: I usually use an OLE DB Source but I've never tried putting a huge query in it.  You do have the option of pulling the query from a variable and that might work better.  Alternatively you might try using an ExecuteSQL task that can pull the code from a file.  I'm not sure how that would work, but you could try creating a table in the tempdb 

    USE tempdb; 
    GO
    CREATE TABLE dbo.mytemptable

Then reference the table from your source as tempdb.dbo.mytemptable.  Then after your data flow have another EXECUTE SQL task that drops the table.